# Condition for the expression to have integer values solution.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have an expression as follows:
$$\lambda=\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}(2b+1)-\frac{1}{2}\right),\quad where\; \alpha\in[0,1]\;\text{and $b$ is a positive integer number}.$$
What is the condition on $\alpha$ for which $\lambda$ is an integer?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Doug, I believe that for $\alpha=1$ , $\lambda$ is an integer. but since $\alpha\in[0,1]$, I am still not sure what are the other values of $\alpha$ for which  $\lambda$ is an integer.

Comment: We need $\alpha(2b+1)-1=2\lambda$ for some integer $\lambda$. This implies $$0\leqslant \alpha = \frac{2\lambda+1}{2b+1}\leqslant 1\implies 0\leqslant 2\lambda+1\leqslant 2b+1$$ Thus, for any integer $\lambda$ such that $0\leqslant \lambda\leqslant b$, you have $\alpha = \frac{2\lambda+1}{2b+1}$ as a solution (in fact, every solution has this form).

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Yes, I got my answer. Thank you so much